# showing 404 error Page not found in magento 1 admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9.4.0

[image]

when iam install any type extension and going to this extension setting then face this 404 error.plz give me solution.

i am clean cache and reindex but provlem not solved.

Answer (score 0):

> just log out once from admin and re-loigin and go to admin. Now go to
>   that. Magento 1 has this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

my checkout page not work plz give me solution